# A way to initiate Windows image backup with Task scheduler?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, disk-image, windows-backup

Windows has a built in image backup (disk image)(system image) tool. How can I initiate it to take a backup to a certain location automatically with task scheduler?
If I could create a bat file then I could run it with scheduler but such code exceeds my windows coding skills. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: If you mean the windows backup tool, you can schedule directly from that program, which I believe uses a scheduled task.

Comment: Ooh! I've found it! Thanks! I was not aware of this.

Comment: I've posted an answer for you, so you can mark it as solved so everyone else knows you're no longer need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the windows backup tool which you can get to from the *Control Panel* > *Backup and Restore (Windows 7)*

You can set a schedule by choosing `Set up Backup`.

Once you get to the `Review your backup settings` screen, you can change the schedule, which by default is set every sunday at 19:00.